# How to share from an app to Xamarin macOS

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking to add the availability to my application to receive content through share option from Note native apple application. I want my application appear in the list below.
Thanks, Robin.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the new project with the share extension and reference it in the main project.

One more critical part is that you need to declare in extension's info.plist which content you want to import.

Also of note, you indicated by the tag that you use Xamarin.Forms. It might be complicated to use Xamarin.Forms for the user interface in the Mac share extension. I would believe it is possible, but I don't think anyone did that and published info on how to do it.